# JavaScript - unable to determine passed object name

Tags: javascript, object, attributes

cannot figure out how to get the name of passed object,
please consider this code:

```
let a = {value: 9}
a['JS'] = {value: 5}
a['BS'] = {value: 3}

check(a['JS'])

function check(element) {
  console.log(element)
  // here I need to somehow determine that passed element has name `JS`
  // without using extra arguments
}
```

thank you.

P.S. (element.constructor.name doesn't work)

P.P.S.
Found solution which `close` to what I need:

```
let a = {value: 9}
a['JS'] = {value: 5}
a['BS'] = {value: 3}

Object.defineProperty(a['JS'], 'name', {
  enumerable: false,
  writable: true
})

a['JS'].name = 'JS'

check(a['JS'])

function check(element) {
  console.log(element)
}
```

Comment: when you do a['JS'] you are already passing its value...To check whether the a has a key JS should be what you mean?

Comment: no it is not, the child object passed in recursive function over thousand arguments, I don't type anything manually

Comment: yes, whatever you are doing with the thousand arguments, you are sending the value so, when you send the value it will be an object as i can see from the question ?? So, you should be checking for what key is in the value itself like nina has done

Comment: you are just adding property name to the an existing object key to check the name that you just added... how is that even close to the question that you were asking/

Comment: `enumerable: false` is the key,
which makes it invisible for Object.keys(),
which creates a `hidden` property,
which sort of works for me

Comment: okay, if you found your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You could hand over the outer object and check with [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

It is not possible to check an object where the outer object has a wanted key.

```js
function check(element) {
    console.log('JS' in element);
    console.log(element);
}

let a = { value: 9, JS: { value: 5 }, BS: { value: 3 } };

console.log(check(a));
```

Comment: no, object passed like in my example, cannot pass parent

Comment: then it's not possible.

Comment: check my solution